# How to hide Incoming Call Notification when my App is Open (Android)

Tags: java, android

[image]

I want to hide this when my app is open. I want my application to always appear on top. Thank you.

Comment: Don't attach images as links.

Comment: i am sorry, i am new on this site

Comment: @JohnryBautista https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: it says i need more reputation to post images

Comment: Did I get it right? You just want to hide it,  not rejecting the call or muting it,Am I right?

Comment: yes, i just want my app to be always on top when it is open.